# JavaFX CSS with Atom?

Tags: java, css, atom-editor

I am using javaFx for a while now and really liking it so far. i was using intelij Idea ultimate until yesterday when its trial was expired. Now as i don't want to pay for ultimate, and CE doesn't have a CSS editing feature i am trying to switch to ATOM only for CSS editing but ATOM doesn't have any -fx- auto completions defined in it. i tried searching but no answers if anyone know how to add this feature to ATOM please let me know.

P.S. i don't want to switch to any other java IDE as IDEA is way better.

Comment: I think it should be quite easy to build a plugin for [autocomplete-plus](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus) based on existing [CSS Autocomplete package](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-css). Would you like to invest some time in it?

Comment: yeah i think i can do that.

Comment: Created https://github.com/kgeorgiy/atom-autocomplete-javafxcss . Is this you: https://github.com/thvardhan ?

Comment: no its not me. but hey thanks for this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [JavaFX-CSS Autocomplete package](https://github.com/kgeorgiy/atom-autocomplete-javafxcss) for Atom.

Disclaimer: It is a fork of standard [CSS Autocomplete package](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-css) maintained by myself.

Comment: yeah i tried it and find it pretty good. (sorry for late response)